# How to avoid typing the arguments to run() all the time

Tags: python, vlab

In my VLAB python scripts, I am repeatedly typing the same arguments for time_unit and blocking:

```
# nothing for a while
write_port("pwm_0.period", 0)
run(200, "ns", blocking=True)

# start a waveform  
write_port("pwm_0.period", 100)

# see it operate for 2 cycle) 
run(230, "ns", blocking=True)

# change duty cycle
write_port("pwm_0.duty", 10)
run(200, "ns", blocking=True)

# change period
write_port("pwm_0.period", 50)
run(200, "ns", blocking=True)
```

Is there some way I can avoid having to type

```
"ns", blocking=True
```

every time I call `run()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can define a function that takes your specified value as an input, then adds the default suffix:

```
def my_run(num):
    run(num, "ns", blocking=True)
```

---

Now, instead of your above code, this would become:

```
# nothing for a while
write_port("pwm_0.period", 0)
my_run(200)

# start a waveform  
write_port("pwm_0.period", 100)

# see it operate for 2 cycle) 
my_run(230)

# change duty cycle
write_port("pwm_0.duty", 10)
my_run(200)

# change period
write_port("pwm_0.period", 50)
my_run(200)
```

Comment: Hah - well that's pretty obvious, once you mention it :)

Comment: @GreenAsJade :) If this helped you, would you mind accepting it? Thanks!

Comment: Sure will.  I just left it a little while, having had it drummed into me that you don't accept immediately, in case someone comes along with an even better idea...

Comment: :) True, I can't argue with that